# What do I set as a default parameter when customizing models.py in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to ask the user for their city, state and zip when signing up. In my models.py I have:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
...
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

I'm getting the following error when migrating:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'city' to profile without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something t
o populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

What should I put as a method parameter? I tried `default=None`, but that gives an error too.

Comment: Well `city` is non-NULLable `CharField`, so passing none is not possible.

Comment: What should I put as the default?

Comment: well the point is that *we* can not answer that. You have to decide that. Perhaps an empty string. The point is what should happen with *existing* records.

Comment: I did `default=""` but not sure if that's entirely correct.

Comment: There are no existing records. This is a new site.

Comment: that does not matter. Even if it is an empty database, migrations are made to be applied on *any* database. So perhaps you have indeed no records on a development database, but not per se on production, so the migrations do not look to that database, they assume it can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Add null=True to the Field definitions. For eg.,

```
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you using [django-countries](https://pypi.org/project/django-countries/)
It has all the countries with a dropdown in forms and you can use profile.city.flag to get the flag image of the country